# Renaming Panda Dataframe indexes

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am populating a dataframe with a sql statement which is giving me index values of a record count starting with 0.  I am writing a comparison with a Snowflake table that I will import into another dataframe.  I would like to change the index for each record so it would be 'SQL' + current index number and the next dataframe with be 'Snow' + the index number.  When I have both dataframes I will concatenate them and reindex to view the difference.

The SQL part looks like this:

```
import pyodbc as pyo

cnn_sql = (r'Driver={SQL Server};Server=dbserver;"Database=stuff;UID=Me;PWD=Password;')

cnn = pyo.connect(cnn_sql)

sql = 'Select * from table'

dfsql = pd.read_sql(sql, cnn)

print(dfsql)

cnn.close
```

Results are like:

```
     Column1   Column2
0    Green     apple
1    Red       orange
```

Would like to see:

```
        Column1   Column2
SQL0    Green     apple
SQL1    Red       orange
```

Is this possible or am I approaching it incorrectly?

Tried the `index.rename` but that errored out

Answer (score 3):

You can [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```py
out = dfsql.rename(lambda x: f'SQL{x}')

# variant
out = dfsql.rename('SQL{}'.format)
```

Or modify the index in place by converting it to string and prefixing SQL:

```py
dfsql.index = 'SQL'+dfsql.index.astype(str)
```

Output:

```
     Column1 Column2
SQL0   Green   apple
SQL1     Red  orange
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```py
df.index = "SQL" + df.index.astype(str)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     Column1 Column2
SQL0   Green   apple
SQL1     Red  orange
```